# How to verify_password from a database

Tags: php

I'm storing a password in a database, like so:

```
public function add_user($username, $password){

    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //here

    $this->query = $this->conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password)');
    $this->query->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $this->query->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $this->query->execute();
}
```

However, I am not sure how to retrieve it. I know of the function

```
password_verify($password, $hash)
```

But I am not sure how to use it. How do I use it to get a user from a database?

What's the best way for me to verify a password with the following code:

```
public function get_user($username, $password){

    $this->query = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * from users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password');
    $this->query->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $this->query->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $this->query->execute();
    $this->retrieve = $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Any help or guidance would be great. The logic of this has confused me greatly.

Comment: I thought I was hashing the password first?

Comment: Okay, does the PHP 5.5 password_hash not do that for me? :)

Comment: @tmyie - of course it does..... but sadly many developers are still unaware that PHP 5.5 password_hash() actually exists

Comment: Okay, count me in the bunch of folks that just discovered how cool that function is. :)

Comment: @Fluffeh - and one of the coolest things is the ability to use it in earlier versions of PHP than 5.5 via the 100% compatible userland library, giving yourself automatic upgradeability when you do progress to PHP 5.5

Comment: @MarkBaker Hey, coming here to answer questions is how I learned some of the coolest things I know. This is *exactly* the sort of thing I love to learn and part of the reason I keep helping folks. I have learned long ago never to underestimate the knowledge of folks asking questions. Right now, I want to give tmyle a damn hug lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, +1 for using PHP's password functions for password hashing!

In contrary to normal hashing functions (such as `md5()`, `sha1()`, etc. - **which should not be used for password hashing**), `password_hash()` will produce a different hash from the same password every time, because it automatically generates a random salt for every hash. This is a great feature that makes your password hashes a lot safer, but it means that you cannot use `password_hash()` to hash the entered password, and use that hashed password in your SQL query (combined with the username) to retrieve the user.

Instead, just retrieve the user based on it's username - and then compare the retrieved password hash with the entered password using [`password_verify()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). This function is able to compare the entered password with the stored hash, even if the cost or algorithm have changed.

Example (using your code):

```
public function get_user($username, $password)
{
    $this->query = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * from users WHERE username=:username LIMIT 1');
    $this->query->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $this->query->execute();
    $user = $this->query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (password_verify($password, $user['password']) {
        // password is correct, return the user
        return $user;
    } else {
        // incorrect password
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Increasing the strength of passwords in the future

As I said before, the new password API allows to upgrade the strength of newly generated password hashes without breaking older ones. This is because the cost and the algorithm (as well as the salt, by the way) are stored within the hash.

It is advisable to increase the cost over time, as available hardware becomes stronger (decreasing the time it would take for an attacker to brute-force a password).

If you decide to do so, or if you decide to use another hashing algorithm, don't forget to add a check using [`password_needs_rehash()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php) in your login procedure. This way existing passwords will be re-hashed as well.

If the function (called with the hash from the database as a parameter) returns true, simply run `password_hash()` again and overwrite the old hash in the database with the new hash. This can obviously only be done when users log in, because that is the only time you should have access to the plain-text passwords.

Comment: It isn't just the cost or algorithm that changes the password_hash() result.... every use of password_hash() creates a new salt, so the result will be different because of that as well.... but +1 for providing a decent explanation of why to use password_hash() and thesample code

Comment: Oops, yes, I completely forgot about that! Thanks, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `password_needs_rehash()`. Is this something I should be using based on the code you've seen?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't very clear. **No, you don't need that right now.** However, if you (or PHP) change the default configuration in the future (increasing the cost, or using a different algorithm), you do not only want to hash new passwords using that configuration, but you also want to rehash the existing ones. `password_needs_rehash()` checks if a password needs to be rehashed (you pass it the hash from the database) so you can re-run `password_hash()` and store the result in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Retrieve the user record using

```
SELECT * from users WHERE username=:username
```

Then compare the password retrieved from the database against the user-entered password using [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)