# password_verify not returning true

Tags: php, hash

I'm new to this, and still learning, and as per suggestion I was replacing my md5 encrypted passwords with bcrypt, but the password_verify isnt returning true for some reason.

From the controller:

```
$old_pass = $this->input->post('old_password');
```

In the Model:

```
function edit_member($user_info, $old_pass)
{
    $id_user = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
    $user_pass = $this->db->query("SELECT password FROM membros WHERE id_user='" . $id_user . "'")->result();
    if (password_verify($old_pass, $user_pass[0]->password)) {
        $this->db->where('id_user', $id_user);
        $this->db->update('membros', $user_info);
        redirect('/cpanel');
    } else {
        //redirect('/edit_account/edit');
        print_r("A password não coincide");
        echo anchor('/cpanel', 'Voltar');
    }
    /*print_r($user_pass[0]->password);
    print_r($old_pass);*/
}
```

Could anyone please tell me how to fix it?

Cheers,
Baya

EDIT:

First thing I did was updating the password on the db with the new encryption, by editing the user through the edit_member function (just so I can show how the password was updated on the db):

```
function edit_member() {
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $user_info = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)."\n"
        );
       $old_pass = $this->input->post('old_password');
       $this->load->model('membership_model');
       $this->membership_model->edit_member($user_info, $old_pass);


}
```

Comment: Set statement is missing in update query!!!

Comment: and the print_r($user_pass[0]->password) returns the right value ?

Comment: datatype and length of the password colum in your membros table?

Comment: @Mark Baker: varchar 255

Comment: @Baya get a look at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910725/how-to-verify-password-from-a-database) it can be useful

Comment: @Asma: will do, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was because the password had been changed into the db with

password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)."\n"

(which I kinda copied from other people posts)

as soon as I deleted the ."\n" bit it started working (I have no idea what this does, like I said, I kinda copied it from other people -.- )

Thanks for everyone who took a look at the issue, and sorry for wasting your time -.-

Cheers,
Baya

Comment: The "\n" is a newline character. Basically you were appending a new line to all of your password hashes, which would make them impossible to verify.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that to me!

Cheers,
Baya

Answer (score 1):

If `password_verify` isn't returning true, it's because:

1. You have not re-hashed the old passwords into bcrypt; OR
2. Your passwords are stored incorrectly; OR
3. You're entering the wrong password

My guess is #1, in which case you need to update your login logic to do the following:

1. MD5 the input password, check if this matches the hash in the database. If so, update the hash in the database using [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).
2. Run [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) on the user password, against the hash in the database.

A lot of my legacy systems work somewhat like this, updating user passwords as they go along (after 6 months or so, I tend to send them a reminder to change their password and disable the old MD5 password).

Comment: Hi Matt,

1. I did update the password into the db before trying the password_verify function by updating the user on the db with
 $user_info = array(
                //edited out or the comment would be too long
                'password' => password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)."\n"
            );

2. I'm storing them as varchar(255)

3. i've checked and double check, and re-updated the password a couple times on the db to make sure I was typing it correctly;

Comment: Hi @Baya, did you `password_hash` the passwords, or the md5 hashes of the passwords? Just to clarify.

Comment: The password. I've replaced the md5() with password_hash() and entered a new password

Comment: I've edited the original post just so to show the controller function through which I updated the password on the db